# webcam installation on HP Probook

Tags: 12.04, laptop, hp, webcam

I am using HP Probook 4520s . My laptop have webcam (Camera Inside) , but I can not reach it and use webcam anyway. How can I install or reinstall webcam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install cheese, an application that can take pictures and record video from you webcam. Install it from the ubuntu software centre. and launch it cheese.